# Typeorm query internal server error with special characture " ' "

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, nest

I am getting an `Internal server error` while query with a special character.

```
  .where(
    new Brackets((qb) => {
      qb.where(`university.status = 'Active'`);
      if (data.filter && Object.keys(data.filter).length > 0) {
        Object.keys(data.filter).forEach(function (key) {
          // check condition operand
          if (key.includes('Id')) {
            condOperand = ' = ';
            likeOp = '';
          } else {
            condOperand = ' ILIKE ';
            likeOp = '%';
          }
          qb.andWhere(
            `university.${key} ${condOperand} ('${likeOp}${data.filter[key]}${likeOp}')`,
          );
        });
      }
    }),
  )
```

Payload

```
{
    "filter": {
        "universityName": "Bishop's University"
    },
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "sortField": "universityId",
    "sortOrder": "ASC"
}
```

I have see in filter at university name. Code works fine with out '. How can I fix that ?